# Jquery function doesn't work (with smarty)

Tags: jquery, function, click, smarty, toggle

I can't find whats the wrong with this script. Please help me!

```
{elseif $text[i].text == "%SubPages"}

<!-- js-->
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#button_{/literal}{$text[i].id}{literal}").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$("#settings_{/literal}{$text[i].id}{literal}").toggle();
});
$("#settings_{/literal}{$text[i].id}{literal}").click(function(event) {
$(this).hide();
});
});
</script>
{/literal}  

<img src='images/subpages.png' />
<!-- button msg-->
<input type="button" id="button_{$text[i].id}" value="[szerkesztés]">
<!-- loading msg-->
<div class="loading_message" id="settings_{$text[i].id}"><div id="message_content"><b><b><b>
asdasdasdasd 
</b></b></b></div></div>
{/if}
```

My problem is the div (class loading msg) does not appear on click. Why?

The HTML source code:

```
<li class="default" id="listItem_1041">
<a class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" id="1041" onclick="return ajaxTextKill(this.getAttribute('id'));"></a>
<!-- js-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#button_1041").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$("#settings_1041").toggle();
});
$("#settings_1041").click(function(event) {
$(this).hide();
});
});
</script>

<img src="images/subpages.png">

<!-- button msg-->
<input type="button" id="button_1041" value="[szerkesztés]">

<!-- loading msg-->
<div class="loading_message" id="settings_1041"><div id="message_content"><b><b><b>
asdasdasdasd 
</b></b></b></div></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please show the parsed HTML end result, not the Smarty source code.

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML, does your JS code look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the loading_message class is displayed and the jquery toggle will hide it. Try adding a display none to that div or use instead of

```
$("#settings_1041").toggle();
```

this one:

```
$("#settings_1041").show();
```

Comment: Nem jó így sem, már próbáltam így is. :( / It doesn't work either, i already tried this way too. :(

Comment: I tried with your generated code and it worked after I added a display:none style to the "loading_message" div.

[Kiprobaltam a generalt kododat es nalam mukodott rendesen miutan a "loading_message"-es div-nek adtam egy "display:none" stilust.]